# Original paper for Young's double slit experiments

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to find the original papers describing Young's double slit experiments including his experimental set-ups and findings. I've tried looking and all I can find is http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/63005#page/498/mode/1up and 
http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/92/12 But neither are papers describing the experiments.

Comment: This is not about history of science in anyway.

Comment: @KprimeX reference requests have been allowed, and there have been upvoted questions approved by mods asking for original papers

Comment: But the tag is not of reference request.

Comment: I have already added it, waiting for approval.

Comment: See here http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/how-did-young-perform-his-double-slit-experiment

Comment: I believe his original experiment was with a single human hair and not a double slit. You might try looking for that.

Comment: Hi TheStrangeQuark. Does the post linked by @Joseph answer your question?

Comment: @KprimeX This question *is*, in my view, on-topic on this site.

Comment: http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/resolve/display/bsb10057961.html

Answer (score 0):

In this [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:HolgerFiedler/Ecxerpt_Young) I made an excerpt for myself. All citations are originally in English, some comments are in German. At the end there is a link to "A Course of Lectures on Natural Philosophy and the Mechanical Arts".

BTW, diffraction of light was known long before Young. [Francesco Maria Grimaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_Maria_Grimaldi) wrote in his book "Physicomathesis de lumine, coloribus et iride aliisque annexis, libri II" in 1665 about diffraction from a rod and a pinhole.

An amazing fact is, that [Young's sketches](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Young_Course_V.2_Plate_XX_liquid_waves.PNG) about water waves and their interferences sometimes is interpreted as a sketch for light interference (Fig. 267).

[image]

Comment: ...so do you have a link to the original sources or not?