# How close were the slits in Young's experiment?

Tags: physics, light

How close were the slits in the Young's double slit experiment in 1804 (the second one) and how were they realized?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/how-did-young-perform-his-double-slit-experiment): I am not asking about how the experiemnts were performed, I am asking the measure of the distance of the slits.

The answer to the [question linked](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/how-did-young-perform-his-double-slit-experiment) doesn't provide the information I am asking.

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/how-did-young-perform-his-double-slit-experiment/2634 may point you in the right direction

Comment: @JonCuster they link a book but I can't find the information I am looking for (the sdistance of the slits) inside it

Comment: Also you have a reopen vote about your own question.